# Generating ground control points with GRASS?

Tags: qgis-grass-plugin, grass-7.2

I want to find out matching ground control points in two images for auto georeferencing and grass manual says that `i.points.auto` will do the job.

I am using Grass 7.2 but couldn't find this plugin.